# When inheriting from a class, its inner classes still inherit from the parent

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

When making a subclass, its inner classes will always subclass from the parent, not its child.

```
class Create
  class Draft < self
    # code
class Update < Create
  # Update::Draft's is implicitly created, but its parent is Create, not `Update`. Why?
```

`Create::Draft.superclass` will return `Create`. That's fine. But `Update::Draft.superclass` will return `Create` too. I want `Update::Draft` to inherit from `Update` class.

Comment: Where is `Update::Draft`?

Comment: I think you are trying to ask "Can I have `Update` inherit from `Create`, and have `Update::Draft` inherit from Update." If you redefine `Draft` in Update, you can. But that defeats the point. It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @sawa `Update::Draft` implicitly inherits `Create`, while I want it to inherit from `Update`

Comment: What is implicit inheritance?

Comment: @sawa `Draft` is an inner class of `Create`, implicitly copied to `Update` because `Update` inherits from `Create`. Huh. As it inherits from `self`, I expected `Update::Draft` to inherit from `Update`

Comment: @Mohamad, I want `Update::Draft` to have _the same content_  (to avoid code duplication) as `Create::Draft`, BUT to inherit from `Update`

Comment: You might have more luck getting an answer if you edited your code to be valid Ruby and to actually demonstrate (e.g. with some inherited methods) the behavior you're seeing and the behavior you want.

Comment: @justso *"to avoid code duplication"* - this is not what inheritance is for. Put the shared code into a *module* and include it in both, `Update::Draft` and `Create::Draft`.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby doesn't have nested classes, which also means it doesn't have virtual classes (obviously, since virtual classes are a special case of nested classes). If you want to use virtual classes, you need to use a language which supports them, such as Beta, gBeta, or [newspeak](/questions/tagged/newspeak) (I don't know of any others).

Since virtual classes are nested classes that are virtual, you can sort-of fake them in Ruby with methods (which are nested inside classes and virtual) returning classes (which are first-class objects in Ruby, and thus can be returned by methods).

That still doesn't solve the problem that the superclass expression is evaluated only *once*, during class declaration, and not everytime for every message send, though. Again, [newspeak](/questions/tagged/newspeak) does this, so you could just use that.

There are other problems with your code. For example, you somehow want an `Update::Draft` class to magically appear. If you want a fourth class, you need to define a fourth class. There is no fourth class. There isn't even a fourth constant. It's just constant lookup rules. `Update` doesn't have a constant named `Draft`, so Ruby continues looking in the lexically enclosing class (which is `Object`), which also doesn't have a constant named `Draft`, so it continues looking in the superclass and finds it there. Nothing appeared. It was always there.

Since there is only one class, it cannot have to different superclasses at different times, you really need to classes.

What you basically want is *class hierarchy inheritance*, which is a feature enabled by virtual classes. [newspeak](/questions/tagged/newspeak)'s *parser combinator library* is a great example of the use of class hierarchy inheritance.

Comment: It *does* magically appear because of inheritance. Hovewer, it simply refers to `Create::Draft`

Comment: No, it doesn't. There is no fourth class. There isn't even a fourth constant. It's just constant lookup rules. `Update` doesn't have a constant named `Draft`, so Ruby continues looking in the lexically enclosing class (which is `Object`), which also doesn't have a constant named `Draft`, so it continues looking in the superclass and finds it there. Nothing appeared. It was always there.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation